# PHPmailer server error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following code that works on my localhost apache.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require ('bin\PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$uname = "rybnikzahradne@rybnikzahradne.sk";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.rybnikzahradne.sk';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username   = $uname; 
$mail->Password   = "********"; 

$mail->From = $uname;
$mail->AddAddress($uname);

$mail->Subject = $_POST["from"];

$mail->Body = $_POST["message"];

$mail->AltBody = 'sprava';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message sent";
}
```

But when I upload it on my server it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'bin\PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php55/lib/php') in /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/3/b/3b4145df-8ba9-4552-835f-4e0224ac066d/rybnikzahradne.sk/web/objednavky3.php on line 5
```

Comment: Have you uploaded `bin\PHPMailerAutoload.php` and is the case of the filename exactly like this?

Comment: @TheConstructor Yep, Ive checked it twice.

Comment: Have you tried changing the require-statement to use `bin/PHPMailerAutoload.php` (forward slash)?

Comment: @TheConstructor LOL thanks it works now, write an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While PHP will accept `\` and `/` on Windows, on *nix Systems you probably have to use `/` as path-separator, so change your line to

```
require ('bin/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

and it should work on both systems.